# Getting the section/subsection etc names in a R Markdown file

Tags: r, r-markdown

I wonder if there is a way to write a block of code in a R Markdown file such that it could return the name of each sections (and subsections etc.) in **this** R Markdown file as character vector(s)?

Basically, I am trying to get the name of all the sections and their subsections (and the sub-subsections etc) to do some analysis, and I would like to have this process automated so that I don't have to manually record the new name every time I add some new section into this R Markdown file.

Many thanks!

Comment: Can the block of code be outside the RMarkdown file it is extracting the names from?

Comment: @henrik_ibsen I think that's the point, I would like to do the analysis inside the RMarkdown file itself

Comment: Not sure if this is feasible for your case, but something along the lines of `readLines("path/to/document.Rmd")[grepl("# ",readLines("path/to/document.Rmd"))]` could work, then include it in a chunk in your document.Rmd. Change "# " depending on how you define sections. It will report itself due to "# " in `grepl`, but should be easy enough to remove.

Comment: You need to have a comment-free file for this to work. Need to remove all r block first (assuming cat and asis option in R blocks is not used for declaring sections)